# limit download speed using apache mod_throttle

Tags: php, apache

I want to limit the download speed of each download in my website.

I have mod_throttle installed but I couldn't find how to limit the bandwidth per file.

for example, limit each download with max speed - 1000KB/s

what's the configuration needed for this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257084/how-can-i-add-a-download-speed-limit-to-this-php-script

Comment: You can try this it work for me :
http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/web-bandwidth-limit.html